# Why does Google sometimes display more pages than can be viewed?

Tags: google-search

Take a look at this query: http://www.google.ca/search?q=site:stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com

At the bottom of the page, it shows 5 pages, but when I click on 5, it jumps to page 3.

Why is that?

Comment: I see only 3 pages. But I know what you mean, I've seen it before.

Comment: Now it's showing 6 :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can sometimes happen when there are similar pages that were indexed:

> In order to show you the most relevant
>   results, we have omitted some entries
>   very similar to the 19 already
>   displayed. If you like, you can repeat
>   the search with the omitted results
>   included.

If you click the link at the bottom of the last page, you should see all 5 pages.

For more information, you can see [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=sZPXICDPcKwC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=omitted+results+included+site%3agoogle.com&source=bl&ots=7JfEHfsE7L&sig=yfzBtt-3BD2HF4OfU9WVBmlYSgc&hl=en&ei=2E9GTPnqMpKgsQPNr5XEAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=omitted%20results%20included%20site%3Agoogle.com&f=false) which explains about that feature.

It seems like this is also for optimization reasons. From [Google's page](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70920):

> In addition, when you click on the
>   next page of search results, the total
>   number of search results can change.
>   In this case, we realize that some of
>   the query results are duplicates, and
>   collapse those duplicates so that you
>   can find the specific result you're
>   looking for more easily. Collapsing
>   the duplicates **decreases** the estimated
>   number of results, as well as the
>   overall **number of results pages**.

(emphasis added)